# File upload control not working while running through IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

This is my coding for the upload to eport to excel...it is working fine when i run

through local in case while running through IIS it is not working.....

This is my code....

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RevenueDumpFileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string strFilePathOnServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RevenueDumpFileLocation"];
        String sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(strFilePathOnServer) + RevenueDumpFileUpload.FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
       // RevenueDumpFileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFilePathOnServer) + RevenueDumpFileUpload.FileName);
        OleDbConnection Exlcon = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
        try
        {
            Exlcon.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", Exlcon);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
        objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");
        methodtosave();
    }
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What is not working? What error you receive? Is it the database connection? To few information to have a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact Fileupload will work and should save the file, but there is problem in the connection string when you try to read the uploaded file. It should be the same file path as you are using to save the file.

```
String sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=" + strFilePathOnServer + RevenueDumpFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName + ";
Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
```

Comment: Tell me one thing, what value contain this variable "strFilePathOnServer" ?

Comment: Let us your file is saved ~/Temp/abc.xls, when you try to read the file your connection string should be like that ...  Data Source="~/Temp/abc.xls" as currently you are only give file name, as you have pass the path as you used for saving the file.

Comment: <appSettings>
    <add key="RevenueDumpFileLocation" value="~/ExcelImport/"/>
  </appSettings>

Comment: see my latest coding i have updated it is working fine when i run through local...when run in the iis it is not working...i.e when i give the path and run...

Comment: there is upvote button, if you try, you will get something as well :)

Answer (score 0):

What type of application is this. Is it a Web Forms app? If so:

What do you mean by local and through IIS? Do you mean on the Server IIS?
If you're running the code on the server and it's not working then you are trying to force the server to do something it's not allowed to do.

For security reasons you shouldn't be accessing Excel on the server from an outside source. What you can do, if this is a Web Forms app, is use java script and an active x control to access the client's excel and write client side java script to save the file to the correct directory. There are plenty of examples online, use Google, to do this. I recently had to do this for 2 Web Applications at work.

If not then this might not be your problem.